# Very weird CSS issue on my horizontal menu

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, prestashop-1.6

I have a very strange responsive issues on my prestashop site on the top menu block. Can you please help me solve it?

Only happens on media width 600px, the problem is that the menu subcategories are dropped down automatically by themselves. I do not know why and do not know how to solve it...

Here is the code

```
/*** ESSENTIAL STYLES ***/
.sf-contener {
clear: both;
}
.sf-right {
  margin-right: 14px;
  float: right;
  width: 7px;
}
.sf-menu, .sf-menu * {
margin: 0;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
list-style: none;
}
.sf-menu {
margin: 10px 0;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
width:980px;/* 980 */
background: #383838;
/*  @media (max-width: 450px) {
    .sf-menu {
      display: none; }    */
}
.sf-menu ul {
position: absolute;
top: -999em;
width: 10em; /* left offset of submenus need to match (see below) */
}
.sf-menu ul li {
width: 100%;
}
.sf-menu li:hover {
visibility: inherit; /* fixes IE7 'sticky bug' */
}
.sf-menu li {
float: left;
position: relative;
top: 0;
/*border-right: 1px solid #777;*/
}
.sf-menu a {
display: block;
position: relative;
color:#fff;
}
.sf-menu li:hover ul,
.sf-menu li.sfHover ul {
left: 0;
/*padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;*/
top: 35px; /* match top ul list item height */
z-index: 99;
width:auto;
}
ul.sf-menu li:hover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li.sfHover li ul {
top: -999em;
}
ul.sf-menu li li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover ul {
left: 200px; /* match ul width */
top: 0;
}
ul.sf-menu li li:hover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover li ul {
left: 200px; /* match ul width */
top: 0;
}
ul.sf-menu li li li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li li.sfHover ul {
left: 200px; /* match ul width */
top: 0;
}


/*** DEMO SKIN ***/
.cat-title {
display: none;
}
.sf-menu {
float: left;
margin-bottom: -2em;
width: 100%;
height: 75px;
background: url('http://www.aaas.com/themes/assa/img/cabecera.png') repeat left center; 

}
.sf-menu a {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  display:block;
    margin-right:2px;
    padding: 0 22px 0 20px;
    line-height:35px;   
    border: 10;
    text-decoration:none; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family:Handlee;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  { /* visited pseudo selector so IE6 applies text colour*/
color: #916e6e;
white-space:nowrap;
}
.sf-menu li ul {
  border:1px solid #f1b6b1; box-shadow:2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  width:500px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 23px 0px 0px 0px;
  top:0;
  background: white;
}
.sf-menu li li {
background: white; 
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height:35px; 
  line-height:35px; 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

}
.sf-menu li li a {
font-size: 16px;
text-transform: capitalize;
top:0;  
}
/*
ul.sf-menu li a {
  padding-right: 2.25em;
  min-width: 1px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
*/
.sf-menu li li li {
background: white;
width:140px;
}
.sf-menu a:focus, .sf-menu a:hover, .sf-menu a:active {
   font-weight: bold; 
   color: white;
   background: url('http://www.sasa.com/themes/sasa/img/boton-b.png') no-repeat center 0px; 
}
.sf-menu ul li:hover, .sf-menu ul li.sfHover,
.sf-menu ul li a:focus, .sf-menu ul li a:hover, .sf-menu ul li a:active {
background: #eecfd0; //#4e4e4e; 
outline: 0;
} 
/*** arrows **/
.sf-menu a.sf-with-ul {
padding-right:  2.25em;
min-width: 1px; /* trigger IE7 hasLayout so spans position accurately */
padding-top: 20px;
margin-top: -20px;
}
.sf-sub-indicator {
position: absolute;
display: block;
right: 10px;
top: 1.05em; /* IE6 only */
width: 10px;
height: 35px;
text-indent:  -999em;
overflow: hidden;
background: url('../img/arrows-ffffff.png') no-repeat -10px -100px; /* 8-bit indexed alpha png. IE6 gets solid image only */
}
a > .sf-sub-indicator {  /* give all except IE6 the correct values */
top: 11px;
background-position: 0 -100px; /* use translucent arrow for modern browsers*/
}
/* apply hovers to modern browsers */
a:focus > .sf-sub-indicator,
a:hover > .sf-sub-indicator,
a:active > .sf-sub-indicator,
li:hover > a > .sf-sub-indicator,
li.sfHover > a > .sf-sub-indicator {
background-position: -10px -100px; /* arrow hovers for modern browsers*/
}


/* point right for anchors in subs */
.sf-menu ul .sf-sub-indicator { background-position:  -10px 0; }
.sf-menu ul a > .sf-sub-indicator { background-position:  0 0; }
/* apply hovers to modern browsers */
.sf-menu ul a:focus > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul a:hover > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul a:active > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul li:hover > a > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul li.sfHover > a > .sf-sub-indicator {
background-position: -10px 0; /* arrow hovers for modern browsers*/
}


/*** shadows for all but IE6 ***/
.sf-shadow ul {
background: url('../img/shadow.png') no-repeat bottom right;
padding: 0 8px 9px 0;
-moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 17px;
-moz-border-top-right-radius: 17px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 17px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 17px;
}
.sf-shadow ul.sf-shadow-off {
background: transparent;
}
li.sf-search {
  background: inherit;
  float: right;
  line-height: 25px;
  background:transparent;
}
li.sf-search input {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin: 18px 6px 0 0;
  background: #fff url('../../../../img/search-zoom3.png') no-repeat left center;
  border:1px solid #777;
}


/* hack IE7 */
.sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited {height:34px !IE;}
.sf-menu li li {
width:200px;
background:#726f72 !IE;
}

#block_top_menu .category-thumbnail {
  display:none;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  float: none; }
  #block_top_menu .category-thumbnail div {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33333%; }
    #block_top_menu .category-thumbnail div img {
      max-width: 100%; }
#block_top_menu li.category-thumbnail {
  padding-right: 0; }




/* Mobile Item */
.sf-menu-phone-item { display:none; }
#sf-menu-phone-trigger { display:none; position:absolute; top:7px; right:0; background:url('http://www.sasa.com/themes/sasas/img/icon-mobile-nav.png') top right no-repeat #29addd; width:50px; height:50px; text-indent:-9999px; border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s; }
#sf-menu-phone-trigger:hover { background-color:#333; }
#sf-menu-phone-trigger.active { background-position:bottom right; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 999px) {
    .sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  {font-size:13px;}
}
/* Tablet Only Queries */
@media only screen and (min-width: 531px) and (max-width: 786px)  { 
    .sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  {font-size:12px;}
}

/* Phone Only Queries */
@media only screen and (max-width: 530px) { 
    .sf-menu a{
        top:5px;
    }
    #sf-menu-header {height:auto; }
    #sf-menu-top-nav {margin-left:-2%; margin-right:-2%;}
    /*.sf-menu {display:none; } */
    .sf-menu {width:100%; height:auto; margin:10px 0 0 0; position:static !important}
    .sf-menu li {width:100%; background:#f4f4f4;  border-top:1px solid #fff !important; border-bottom:1px solid #999 !important; -webkit-border-radius:0; border-radius:0; }
    .sf-menu li:hover {background:#de8686;}
    .sf-menu li ul {width:100%; position:static !important; background:#ccc;}
    .sf-menu li li {width:100% !important; background:#ccc; }
    /*.sf-menu li li li {display:none !important;}*/
    .sf-menu-phone-item { display:block; }
    #sf-menu-phone-trigger { display:block; }
    .sf-search {padding:10px;} 
    #searchbox {margin-left:15px;}
    #searchbox input[type="text"] {width:80%;}
    #searchbox input[type="text"]:focus, #searchbox input[type="text"]:hover {width:80%;}
    #searchbox .button {width:10%;}
    #header_logo { padding-right:50px; text-align:left !important;}
}
```

Thank you very much I really appreciate your help

Comment: Can you create a [minimal, concrete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), either with the in-built code snippet or as an externally hosted one, like on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? Links to live sites are discouraged because they are prone to link rot and lose relevance to future users.

Comment: I think it must be a simple issue if you could take a look at live site I'll appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the browser's width increases, there's some JavaScript running somewhere that adds display: none as inline CSS to the element. The problem is that this script only works when the browser's width is larger than 600px. To solve this problem, you'll have to apply the following css to your sub-menu:

```
.sf-menu li ul {
    display: none;
}

.sf-menu li a:hover + ul {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Solve the issue, however now it doesn't get dropdown on mouse over....

Comment: I found the source of the problem, the js file.
I commented out 2 lines and seems to work ok.

function responsiveMenu()
{
   if ($(document).width() <= 767 && responsiveflagMenu == false)
 {
 // menuChange('enable');
 // responsiveflagMenu = true;
 }
 else if ($(document).width() >= 768)
 {
  menuChange('disable');
  responsiveflagMenu = false;
 }
}

however now on phone resolution do not get dropdown on click...

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Nice, I already told you that there's some JS script applying CSS. If my answer, or other answers helped, can you please vote them up and choose the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

There is some modification made in javascript, and as the code is obfuscate/optimized, it will be difficult to tell what you have to correct. 
Setting a CSS rule above that is a kind of rubber patch, you should first find the location in the source code where the modification occurs. May be you could append this code in your question.

There is also a problem with how your submenus are generated. The one for "novedades" is a child an `ul` element in the "Washi Tape" `li`

```
<ul class="sf-menu clearfix menu-content">
    <li><a href="/novedades" title="Novedades">Novedades</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.dulcewashitape.com/index.php?category_rewrite=washi-tape&amp;controller=category" title="Washi Tape">Washi Tape</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.dulcewashitape.com/index.php?category_rewrite=por-colores&amp;controller=category" title="Por colores">Por colores</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www.dulcewashitape.com/index.php?category_rewrite=amarillo&amp;controller=category" title="Amarillo">Amarillo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.dulcewashitape.com/index.php?category_rewrite=azul&amp;controller=category" title="Azul">Azul</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.dulcewashitape.com/index.php?category_rewrite=gris&amp;controller=category" title="Gris">Gris</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.dulcewashitape.com/index.php?category_rewrite=marron&amp;controller=category" title="Marrón">Marrón</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.dulcewashitape.com/index.php?category_rewrite=naranja&amp;controller=category" title="Naranja">Naranja</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.dulcewashitape.com/index.php?category_rewrite=negro&amp;controller=category" title="Negro">Negro</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.dulcewashitape.com/index.php?category_rewrite=rojo&amp;controller=category" title="Rojo">Rojo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.dulcewashitape.com/index.php?category_rewrite=rosa&amp;controller=category" title="Rosa">Rosa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.dulcewashitape.com/index.php?category_rewrite=verde&amp;controller=category" title="Verde">Verde</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.dulcewashitape.com/index.php?category_rewrite=violeta&amp;controller=category" title="Violeta">Violeta</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.dulcewashitape.com/index.php?category_rewrite=lisos&amp;controller=category" title="Lisos">Lisos</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.dulcewashitape.com/index.php?category_rewrite=lineas&amp;controller=category" title="Líneas">Líneas</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.dulcewashitape.com/index.php?category_rewrite=topos&amp;controller=category" title="Topos">Topos</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.dulcewashitape.com/index.php?category_rewrite=estampados&amp;controller=category" title="Estampados">Estampados</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.dulcewashitape.com/index.php?category_rewrite=naturaleza&amp;controller=category" title="Naturaleza">Naturaleza</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.dulcewashitape.com/index.php?category_rewrite=infantil&amp;controller=category" title="Infantil">Infantil</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.dulcewashitape.com/index.php?category_rewrite=corazones&amp;controller=category" title="Corazones">Corazones</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.dulcewashitape.com/index.php?category_rewrite=estrellas&amp;controller=category" title="Estrellas">Estrellas</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.dulcewashitape.com/index.php?category_rewrite=con-mensaje&amp;controller=category" title="Con mensaje">Con mensaje</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.dulcewashitape.com/index.php?category_rewrite=purpurinaglitter&amp;controller=category" title="Purpurina/Glitter">Purpurina/Glitter</a></li>
            <li class="category-thumbnail"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sf-search noBack" style="float:right">
        <form id="searchbox" action="http://www.dulcewashitape.com/index.php?controller=search" method="get">
            <p>
                <input type="hidden" name="controller" value="search" />
                <input type="hidden" value="position" name="orderby" />
                <input type="hidden" value="desc" name="orderway" />
                <input type="text" name="search_query" placeholder="Buscar" value="" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes! That's also a problem. This 2 categories get different element but should be the same. I also do not know how to change that!

Answer (score -1):

I had a quick look at the site.  As I suspected display:none disappears at that point.  So, its  an issue with your csss.  They are too complicated for me right now.  A suggestion is to put display:none !important which will override other rules.